# Private internet access appears to connect but nothing will load

Tags: vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and recently installed private internet access, I remember having the same problem on windows and I think this fixed it from what I remember: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/guides/windows/windows/windows-legacy-change-dns

I'm really not confident with using the terminal so I'd like to know how I can do this and be sure I'm not messing things up.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (from 2014.April) came with 5 years of supported life, which ends this month.  Are you sure you don't want to consider upgrading to 16.04 LTS (or more-modern) as you'll likely have to repeat these steps next month when you will need to upgrade, or are you intending to switch from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 14.04 ESM? thus it's needed (ESM or extended paid support is off-topic here as it has different support options)

Comment: @guiverc It was the only install disc I had and it's the version I'm most familiar with since I'm having to relearn a bunch of stuff. I'm not sure whether I want to upgrade or not but if I do then I'd at least like to try this and see if it works, and if it does then I might know what to do next time. Also do you know if there's still any issues with nvidia or broadcom devices? If I do upgrade then I'd especially like to know if there's any chance of my wifi breaking again.